# Processing & Splitting Lines As Associative Array in Zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm playing around with a non-sensical script for learning purposes (just writing some examples of variable scope handling). I define several variables like this:

```
sb_var_global=TRUE
typeset    sb_var_typeset=TRUE
typeset -g sb_var_typeset_g=TRUE
declare    sb_var_declare=TRUE
declare -g sb_var_declare_g=TRUE

export sb_var_export=TRUE
typeset -gx sb_var_typeset_gx=TRUE
declare -gx sb_var_declare_g=TRUE
```

I then display them, like this:

```
echo "Set variables ..."
set | grep sb_var_
echo "\n Environment variables ..."
env | grep sb_var_
```

This generates output like this:

```
Displaying *set* variables ...
sb_var_declare=TRUE
sb_var_declare_g=TRUE
sb_var_export=TRUE
sb_var_func_declare_g=TRUE
sb_var_func_global=TRUE
sb_var_func_typeset_g=TRUE
sb_var_global=TRUE
sb_var_readonly=TRUE
sb_var_typeset=TRUE
sb_var_typeset_g=TRUE
sb_var_typeset_gx=TRUE

Displaying *env* variables ...
sb_var_export=TRUE
sb_var_typeset_gx=TRUE
sb_var_declare_g=TRUE
```

I started trying to process that output as an associative array, but I can't get the syntax quite right.

This loops over each line, then executes a string expansion against each line (individually) to split each line into an array (not what I want):

```
for var in $(set | grep sb_var_); do
  tokens=(${(s:=:)var})
  print ${tokens[1]} ${tokens[2]}
done
```

The standard way to process an associative array is:

```
for key val in ${(kv)assoc_array}; do
    echo "$key -> $val"
done
```

To use this type of syntax, I need to execute the command substitution, split each line as it is returned, and store the results in an associative array that is passed directly to the for loop construct. I thought this might look something like:

```
for key val in ${(kv)${(s:=:)$(set | grep sb_var_)}}; do
    echo "$key -> $val"
done
```

This isn't quite right though and ends up generating output like:

```
sb_var_declare -> TRUE sb_var_declare_g
TRUE sb_var_export -> TRUE sb_var_func_declare_g
TRUE sb_var_func_global -> TRUE sb_var_func_typeset_g
TRUE sb_var_global -> TRUE sb_var_readonly
TRUE sb_var_typeset -> TRUE sb_var_typeset_g
TRUE sb_var_typeset_gx -> TRUE
```

Attempting to split it up to make it a little more managable, I haven't been able to figure out how to get that syntax correct, my best attempt was this (invalid syntax):

```
declare -A values=${(s:=:)$(set | grep sb_var_)}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're missing is telling the arrays you're defining to treat newlines as a separator, rather than the whatever `$IFS` is set to. You should be able to get around this by adding flags to treat them as arrays (`@`), joining the original results with newlines (`F`), and then splitting the output on newlines in the main loop (`F`).

Example:

```
# Notice the new @f and @F flags
for key val in ${(@fkv)${(@Fs:=:)$(set | grep sb_var_)}}; do
  echo "$key -> $val"
done
```